# Earth Engine: Error: Input has missing or invalid affine transform when trying to upload RADARSAT RCM image but works if I load it into QGIS first

Tags: qgis, google-earth-engine, radarsat-2

I'm new to Earth Engine and I cannot figure out how to upload my RCM .tif file into my assets in GEE. I get the following error

```
Error: Input has missing or invalid affine transform. Source filename: 2087044_1_HV.tif (Error code: 3)
```

The file size is 65,478 KB so I do not think it is too big. However, if I select the images in QGIS and then click "Export Layer" it exports it as a TIF file again and save it so its now 243,344 KB, I can upload that into GEE.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this?

Edit: This is the output from `gdalinfo`:

```
gdalinfo 2087044_1_HV.tif
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: 2087044_1_HV.tif
Size is 4937, 6709
GCP Projection =
GEOGCRS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
        ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    CS[ellipsoidal,2],
        AXIS["geodetic latitude (Lat)",north,
            ORDER[1],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        AXIS["geodetic longitude (Lon)",east,
            ORDER[2],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    ID["EPSG",4326]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 2,1
GCP[  0]: Id=1, Info=
          (0.5,0.5) -> (-116.335829151832,60.9547295320172,0)
GCP[  1]: Id=2, Info=
          (165.033340454102,0.5) -> (-116.31723210338,60.9528839682125,0)
GCP[  2]: Id=3, Info=
          (329.566680908203,0.5) -> (-116.29863714031,60.9510358337104,0)
GCP[  3]: Id=4, Info=
          (494.100036621094,0.5) -> (-116.280044375457,60.9491851399533,0)

...

GCP[1301]: Id=1302, Info=
          (4936.5,6708.5) -> (-115.940267335968,60.530183273056,0)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
  TIFFTAG_DATETIME=2022:05:11 14:14:01
  TIFFTAG_IMAGEDESCRIPTION=HV
  TIFFTAG_MAXSAMPLEVALUE=9833
  TIFFTAG_MINSAMPLEVALUE=0
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (    0.0,    0.0)
Lower Left  (    0.0, 6709.0)
Upper Right ( 4937.0,    0.0)
Lower Right ( 4937.0, 6709.0)
Center      ( 2468.5, 3354.5)
Band 1 Block=4937x106 Type=UInt16, ColorInterp=Gray
```

And for another file

```
gdalinfo 2087044_1_HH.tif
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: 2087044_1_HH.tif
Size is 4937, 6709
GCP Projection =
GEOGCRS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
        ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    CS[ellipsoidal,2],
        AXIS["geodetic latitude (Lat)",north,
            ORDER[1],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        AXIS["geodetic longitude (Lon)",east,
            ORDER[2],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    ID["EPSG",4326]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 2,1
GCP[  0]: Id=1, Info=
          (0.5,0.5) -> (-116.335829151832,60.9547295320172,0)
GCP[  1]: Id=2, Info=
          (165.033340454102,0.5) -> (-116.31723210338,60.9528839682125,0)
GCP[  2]: Id=3, Info=
          (329.566680908203,0.5) -> (-116.29863714031,60.9510358337104,0)
GCP[  3]: Id=4, Info=
          (494.100036621094,0.5) -> (-116.280044375457,60.9491851399533,0)

...

GCP[1301]: Id=1302, Info=
          (4936.5,6708.5) -> (-115.940267335968,60.530183273056,0)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
  TIFFTAG_DATETIME=2022:05:11 14:14:01
  TIFFTAG_IMAGEDESCRIPTION=HH
  TIFFTAG_MAXSAMPLEVALUE=23868
  TIFFTAG_MINSAMPLEVALUE=0
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (    0.0,    0.0)
Lower Left  (    0.0, 6709.0)
Upper Right ( 4937.0,    0.0)
Lower Right ( 4937.0, 6709.0)
Center      ( 2468.5, 3354.5)
Band 1 Block=4937x106 Type=UInt16, ColorInterp=Gray
```

Comment: I don't think the file size itself is the problem. Could you provide the output of `gdalinfo` on both files? that should provide more clues about what's happening.

Comment: @OliverLopez They are now included as an edit in my original post. Thanks